# Can I use regex to replace all keywords in a string? (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, regex, string, replace

Here is my code:

```py
# case 1
content = "staging_datastorage"
query_term = "st ta ag"

# case 2
# content = "game_event"
# query_term = "gam ame"

terms = re.findall('[a-z0-9]+', query_term, re.I)
terms.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
term_regex = "|".join(terms)
replace_content = re.sub(rf"({term_regex})", r'<em>\1</em>', content, flags = re.I)
print(replace_content)
```

What I want to do is use the `<em>` HTML tag to highlight some keywords in a table (called `content`) with my input string (`query_term`). The input string contains the keyword I want to highlight and divide by a <kbd>space</kbd>.

For the two cases, the results I want are:

```
case 1:
this is better
<em>stag</em>ing_da<em>tast</em>or<em>ag</em>e
this is also fine(nesting highlight tag): 
<em>s<em>t<em></em>a</em>g</em>ing_da<em>ta<em></em>st</em>or<em>ag</em>e

case 2:
perfect result: 
<em>game</em>_event
fine result: 
<em>g<em>am</em>e</em>_event
```

My code has a bug: for case 2, it only highlights `gam` and not `nam`, this result is not right:
`<em>gam</em>e_event`

I think that this situation is a bit complicated, where one keyword is nesting in another one or one keyword is the beginning (or ending) part of another one.

Can I use regex to solve this?

Comment: Works as intended: If it finds `gam`, it cannot find `ame`, because it searches the remaining part (searches `e_event`)

Comment: Got it, but can I solve this with some methods, like replace twice? or something

Comment: @Aryan Beezadhur Thank you so much, forgive me for my poor English. Thanks again!

Comment: why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: hahaha, you can answer me with JS code :) @MattEllen

Comment: Is there no solution?

Comment: @XuWang I'm lazy and working remotely, so I just answered your question, instead of actually working, lol

Comment: @h4z3 Thanks, the idea#2 is similar with what i think yesterday, and I will try the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, searches are non-overlapping, next found is in the remaining part.

What you can do **idea #1**:

`re.sub` each keyword separately in a loop.

Of course if the searches are overlapping, you could have some `<em>` or `</em>` already in the way - like here, `ame` won't match `am</em>e` - so you need to modify the single-keyword regexes. Include `(?:</?em>)?` between letters.

```
terms = re.findall('[a-z0-9]+', query_term, re.I)
terms.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
replace_content = content
for term in terms:
    term_regex = "(?:</?em>)?".join(term)
    replace_content = re.sub(rf"({term_regex})", r'<em>\1</em>', replace_content, flags = re.I)

print(replace_content)
```

Results for both cases:

```
<em>s<em>t</em><em>a</em>g</em>ing_da<em>ta</em><em>st</em>or<em>ag</em>e
```

```
<em>g<em>am</em>e</em>_event
```

---

**Idea #2**

You could pre-process the keywords themselves, find which prefixes match the suffixes, and merge those in another keywords.

Here: `gam` has suffix `am`, `ame` has prefix `am` -> you add `game` to your terms.

**This idea would give that "perfect result"**

---

**Idea #3***

Do the idea #1, remove nested highlights and merge those just next to each other (ie remove `</em><em>`).

**This idea would give that "perfect result" as well.**

To remove one level of nesting, do:

```
re.sub(r"<em>([^/]*)<em>([^/]*)</em>([^/]*)</em>", r"<em>\1\2\3</em>", replace_content, flags = re.I)
```

The regex works by finding tags in the order of `<em>` `<em>` `</em>` `</em>` (so nested) with any groups of characters without `/` between them (a quick way to make sure we're taking only the nearest closing tag).

Obviously, with only one level of nesting removed, we need to use this in a loop as well - this would be a `while` loop: while replaces is different from last time, replace again = stops when replace doesn't make changes anymore.

```
final_result = ""
while final_result != replace_content:
    final_result = replace_content
    replace_content = re.sub(r"<em>([^/]*)<em>([^/]*)</em>([^/]*)</em>", r"<em>\1\2\3</em>", final_result, flags = re.I)

print(final_result)
```

Case2 has only one replacement needed, so let's see how it works on case1:

```
<em>stag</em>ing_da<em>ta</em><em>st</em>or<em>ag</em>e
```

Now this only needs the `</em><em>` removal, as I mentioned!

Final piece of code to put after idea #1 code:

```
final_result = ""
while final_result != replace_content:
    final_result = replace_content
    replace_content = re.sub(r"<em>([^/]*)<em>([^/]*)</em>([^/]*)</em>", r"<em>\1\2\3</em>", final_result, flags = re.I)

final_result = final_result.replace("</em><em>", "")
print(final_result)
```

Gives:

```
<em>stag</em>ing_da<em>tast</em>or<em>ag</em>e
```